# Curity server admin console not connecting

Tags: server, identity, curity

I did a fresh installation of curity 7.1.0 on a Linux VM. it installed without any issue and started fine. However I am not able to connect it using admin console.

error:
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to xx.xx.xx.xx:6749. PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR

Answer (score 2):

A `RESET_ERROR` often indicates a problem with the infrastructure in my experience.

You can try the following

1. Clear the cache of your browser
2. Test with a different browser
3. Check network settings, i.e. firewall, VPN, proxies, port openings...